# ffmpeg horizonal flip makes video shorter

Tags: matplotlib, ffmpeg

I am trying to use the following command to flip my video horizontally

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vf hflip -c:a copy video_flip.mp4
```

However, I discovered that it makes the video shorter, which I did not intend.

I originally created the video using FFMpegWriter in Python, the code looks something like this

```
metadata = dict(title='video', artist='me', comment='Watch this!')
writer = FFMpegWriter(fps=25, metadata=metadata)
with writer.saving(fig, "video.mp4", 100):
    for t in range(100):
        ax.cla()        
        ax.plot(x,y)

        writer.grab_frame()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly do you mean "shorter"?

Comment: I mean that not all frames in the original video are in the flipped video.

Comment: So, how many frames did you lose? Out of total?

Comment: Show the complete log from your ffmpeg command. How are you counting frames for both input and output?